# Which tagset to use for training a POS tagger?

Tags: nlp, viterbi

I'm designing a simple POS tagger using the Viterbi algorithm and a Trigram language model. How do I decide which tagset to use for training? (POS tagger for English)

Comment: It depends on what you need the tagged text for.

Comment: I'm new to  NLP and am working on a project to help introduce students to NLP. I've done all my research and I know how to implement a POS tagger using the Viterbi algorithm. I'm confused as to which tagset to use for training as there are so many out there.

Comment: So you're teaching students something you're just learning yourself? And there's no one on the project who can answer that question? I don't think I'd be very pleased as a student of yours.

Comment: Anyway, if this is purely educational, just choose the tagset for which you find the most annotated training data. Or the one with the smallest number of tags, because it might go well with the idea of having a simple tagger.

Comment: I am the student working on the project, I'm not a mentor. I have to decide  
 which tagset to use for my implementation of the project.

Comment: Alright, the Penn Treebank would be a viable option?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misinterpreted your second comment. The Penn Treebank (PTB) is not a tagset, it's an annotated corpus. (The PTB *tagset* is the set of tags used for annotating the PTB.) As a treebank, the PTB includes parse trees, which is more than you need – you only need POS-tag annotations.